# Graph Adjacency List

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

Spent some time implementing a graph as an adjacency list. Looking for suggestions on how to improve this implementation.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class Graph{

public:
     //n is the number of vertices in graph
     Graph(int n)
     {
          N=n;
          E=0;
          //for(int i=0;i < n; ++i)
          for(;n > 0; n--)
          {
              std::vector<int> row;
              adjList.push_back(row);
          }
     }
     //# of vertices
     int Vertices()
     {
         return N;
     }
     //# of Edges
     int Edges()
     {
          return E;
     }
     void addEdge(int v, int w)
     {
          adjList[v].push_back(w);
          adjList[w].push_back(v);
          ++E;
     }

     void  adjVertices(int v)
     {
        std::cout<<"Adjacent vertices of"<< v <<std::endl;
        for(auto &x : adjList[v])
           std::cout<< x << std::endl;
     }

private:
    int N;
    int E;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > adjList;
};

int main()
{
     Graph G(10);
     G.addEdge(3, 4);
     G.addEdge(0, 2);
     G.addEdge(0, 4);
     G.addEdge(0, 9);
     G.adjVertices(0);
     G.adjVertices(4);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First very important thing: Good/clear code without comments is better than bad code with comments. I say this because you are using comments to make up for vague variable and method names. For instance:

> ```
>  //n is the number of vertices in graph
>  Graph(int n)
>  {
>      ....
> ```

Then why not rename `n` to `numberOfVerts`?

Other instances:

> ```
>  //# of vertices
>  int Vertices() { ... }
>
>  //# of Edges
>  int Edges() { ... }
> ```

Would be more clear about their intent if named `getNumOfVertices()` or `getVertexCount()`. Conversely, `getNumOfEdges()` and `getEdgeCount()`.

Still talking about naming, the members `N` and `E` are also very poor names. One is the number of vertices (`N`) and the other the number of edges (`E`). Single letter variable names should generally be avoided, as they are very ambiguous and unclear. One exception to this rule is in loop counters, which historically have been named with `i`, `j`, `k`, and so on, and thus have become a known idiom in programming.

---

You don't need to and should not use a loop to initialize the `adjList` vector.

> ```
>  for(;n > 0; n--)
>  {
>      std::vector<int> row;
>      adjList.push_back(row);
>  }
> ```

That is a very inefficient way of initializing it. `push_back()` might grow the vector several times, incurring a few expensive memory re-allocations. Just [construct the vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with its size, using the *constructor initialization list*:

```
 Graph(int numVerts)
     : numOfVerts(numVerts)
     , numOfEdges(0)
     , adjList(numVerts)
 { }
```

Also worth noting that C++11 allows you to replace the `( )` in the constructor call for the member variables with `{ }`. This is the so called *uniform initialization* syntax.

---

Be [*const correct*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html). Add `const` to methods that don't mutate member data. Get* methods are the common candidates:

```
int Edges() const { return E; }
            ^^^^^
```

---

Don't use `endl` unless you are meant to flush `stdout`. Otherwise, a `"\n"` should be used. Flushing at every print call can significantly bring performance down at no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for the review comments. I will take care and make changes in code. Does const correct change guaranteed any positive performance impact?

Comment: @Steephen, I don't think it would improve performance. Proper use of `const` is meant to make code clearer to the reader and to avoid some common programming errors. Constness can also have implications related to multi-threading, so concurrent programs should pay extra attention to it.